# How to keep original int value with atoi

Tags: c

I am parsing a file with the following content:

```
0x1001
0x1001
0x0004
...
```

Here is part of my code:

```
while(fgets (line, sizeof(line),fp) != NULL)
{
  inst[count] = atoi(line);
  printf("%d\n",inst[count]);
  count++;
 }
```

My `printf()` result is then only zeroes. I would like to keep the exactly same values as written in the parsed file in my array `inst`, but `atoi()` isn't doing the job well. I've also tried `strtoul()` without success.

Is there a way to keep the same format of the integers from the file when passing them to an "int" type in C ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `atoi()` to parse hexadecimal integers, it only handles decimal.

Use [`sscanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf):

```
if(sscanf(line, "%x", &inst[count]) == 1)
  printf("got 0x%x\n", inst[count]);
```

Answer (score 2):

`atoi` does not work on hexdecimal integers. Use `strtoul` instead.

Integer types in c do not have any formatting information. If you want to keep the formatting information you need to keep it on the side.

Answer (score 1):

`atoi` only parses decimal numbers. `atoi` sees digit 0 followed by non-digit x. The non-digit stops the scan. To correctly parse any number (0xaaa, 12, 0777) you need to use `strtol` with 0 passed for `base`.